# Why does JSX syntax error x Expected '}' appear?

Tags: javascript, jsx

keep getting this error in my Navbar.jsx component..

`Error:  x Expected '}', got 'flex' ,---- 16 | <ul className={'list-none flexCenter flex-row ${isMobile && 'flex-col h-full'} :                                                              ^^^^` ----`

Comment: You appear to have a syntax error, but without the code that caused it I don't see how we can help you. Take the [tour] and see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

you missed a } after 'flex-col h-full'}
`<ul className={'list-none flexCenter flex-row ${isMobile && 'flex-col h-full'}}` is what it should be